# WPF is not setting the values to the EF object that is set as Datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, object, datacontext

I have observation/issue/problem.

In my app I have loaded a list of EF objects (Let's call them "Car") that I am setting as the "DataContext" to an "ItemsControl". The ItemsControl has a bunch of controls that represent the Properties of the Object ("Car") like textboxes and similar....

As far as I understood it, If I assign a Property to a control it should be binded, If I change the value in the TextBox it should also be changed in the Object. But this is not happening in my app. Am I missing something?

As far as I know, for the other way around, the property's class needs to implement the Interface "INotifyPropertyChanged" when the change happens from Object->GUI, but nothing like this needs to be done when there is a change from GUI-Object.

Am I missing something, Am I missinformed, or just writing buggy code?

**EDITED - 1st time** - thnx for the suggestion

```
<ItemsControl Name="icRoles" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Name="grdRoles" Background="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="80" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.4*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <!--Subject-->

                <Label Content="Uloga" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="label8" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

                <Label Content="ID:" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <Label Content="Ime Uloge:" Grid.Row="2" Height="28" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <Label Content="Prikazano ime:" Grid.Row="3" Height="28" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <Label Content="Tip Uloge:" Grid.Row="4" Height="28" Name="label4" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <Label Content="Datum Stvaranja:" Grid.Row="5" Height="28" Name="label5" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <Label Content="Datum promjene:" Grid.Row="6" Height="28" Name="label6" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <Label Content="Stanje:" Grid.Row="7" Height="28" Name="label7" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

                <TextBox    Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" Text="{Binding ID}" IsEnabled="False" />
                <TextBox    Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="23" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBox    Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Height="23" Text="{Binding Text}"  />
                <WrapPanel  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Height="25"  />
                <DatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Height="25" SelectedDate="{Binding DateCreated}" IsEnabled="False" />
                <DatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Height="25" SelectedDate="{Binding DateModified}" IsEnabled="False"  />
                <CheckBox   Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" Height="16" IsChecked="{Binding active}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**EDITED - 2nd Time**
I have now set the Mode of the binding to the controls as they are supossed to be. But one strange thing is happening. I have set the Binding of two textboxes to

```
Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

But only the first one is being set to the propery. The fist one stays null.+

Comment: Post at least the Binding Xaml.

Comment: Can you post your code? Check the "DataContext" again and set the binding mode to two way

Comment: Think I found it

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

OK. Solved it from suggestion from [User that helped](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1221336/jasti)

I was missing the binding mode. (Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}")

the second issue is because the control did not save the data into the object because it still had focus. The saving was not commited into the object